# How to extract the title and src of an image with Beautifulsoup or Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

So i have all the page content with:

```py
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
```

then, i did this:

```py
idioma = soup.select(".idioma > span:nth-child(1)")
```

Which gave me this:

```py
[<span>
<img alt="Idioma Aleman" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/ale.png" title="Idioma Aleman"/>
<img alt="Idioma Chino-tradicional" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/chi.png" title="Idioma Chino-tradicional"/>
<img alt="Idioma Coreano" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/cor.png" title="Idioma Coreano"/>
<img alt="Idioma Español" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/esp.png" title="Idioma Español"/>
<img alt="Idioma Español-latino" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/esp.png" title="Idioma Español-latino"/>
<img alt="Idioma Frances" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/fra.png" title="Idioma Frances"/>
<img alt="Idioma Ingles" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/ing.png" title="Idioma Ingles"/>
<img alt="Idioma Italiano" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/ita.png" title="Idioma Italiano"/>
<img alt="Idioma Portugues" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/por.png" title="Idioma Portugues"/>
<img alt="Idioma Ruso" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/rus.png" title="Idioma Ruso"/>
</span>]
```

when i do this to obtain the titles:

```py
idioma = [''.join(elem.find('img')['title']) for elem in idioma if elem]
```

i only got the first one.

```py
['Idioma Aleman']
```

Why im not getting everyone?

Answer (score 1):

**Why yo not getting all title?**

It is because there is only one element in idioma und you use `find()` that only get the first match.

**What you can do is something like this:**

```
idioma = [''.join(elem['title']) for elem in idioma.findAll('img')]
print (idioma)
```

**Output**

```
['Idioma Aleman', 'Idioma Chino-tradicional', 'Idioma Coreano', 'Idioma Español', 'Idioma Español-latino', 'Idioma Frances', 'Idioma Ingles', 'Idioma Italiano', 'Idioma Portugues', 'Idioma Ruso']
```

**Working example in addition based on comment**

```
import bs4

content ='''<span>
<img alt="Idioma Aleman" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/ale.png" title="Idioma Aleman"/>
<img alt="Idioma Chino-tradicional" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/chi.png" title="Idioma Chino-tradicional"/>
<img alt="Idioma Coreano" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/cor.png" title="Idioma Coreano"/>
<img alt="Idioma Español" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/esp.png" title="Idioma Español"/>
<img alt="Idioma Español-latino" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/esp.png" title="Idioma Español-latino"/>
<img alt="Idioma Frances" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/fra.png" title="Idioma Frances"/>
<img alt="Idioma Ingles" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/ing.png" title="Idioma Ingles"/>
<img alt="Idioma Italiano" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/ita.png" title="Idioma Italiano"/>
<img alt="Idioma Portugues" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/por.png" title="Idioma Portugues"/>
<img alt="Idioma Ruso" class="post_flagen" src="https://www.gamestorrents.nu/wp-content/themes/GamesTorrent/css/images/flags/rus.png" title="Idioma Ruso"/>
</span>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Following makes the difference:

```
idiomaSpan = soup.select_one('span')

idioma = [''.join(elem['title']) for elem in idiomaSpan.find_all('img')]
print (idioma)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, this is the console error:

```AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

Comment: That is caused of the `select()` that finds multiple instances and returns a list, so you have to iterate in addition -  Think you can use `select_one()` instead, that only get the first occurrence equivalent to `find()`. Added an example to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

To extract the *title* and *src* attributes from all of the `<span>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` for *title*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("title") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".idioma > span:nth-child(1) img.post_flagen[alt^='Idioma']")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` for *src*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'idioma')]//span//img[starts-with(@alt, 'Idioma') and @class='post_flagen']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```